# Custom object serialization

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

Is there a way to change how an object is serialized in json? for example, the following object:

```cs
class PersonName {
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

var obj = new { 
    pName = new PersonName { 
        Name = "Andrew"
    }
}
```

is serialized as `{"pName": { "name": "Andrew" }}`.

But is there a way to serialize it as `{"pName": "Andrew"}`?

Comment: Is `var obj = new { 
    pName = "Andrew"
    }` an option?

Comment: Why do you define `PersonName` as a custom class instead of simply a `string`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I've managed to get the answer to this one.

A custom converter is needed:

```
public class PersonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var person = value as PersonName;
        if (person == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        serializer.Serialize(writer, person.Name);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var constructorInfo = objectType.GetTypeInfo().GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Single();
        var parameterInfo = constructorInfo.GetParameters().Single();
        var parameterType = parameterInfo.ParameterType;

        var value = serializer.Deserialize(reader, parameterType);
        return Activator.CreateInstance(objectType, new[] { value });
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(PersonName).GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }
}
```

which can be used like this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(PersonConverter))]
public class PersonName
{
    public PersonName(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
class PersonName 
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "pName")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
var obj = new  PersonName { Name = "Andrew" }
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, the op wants `PersonName` wrapped in `obj`

Comment: Maybe you're right. As I understood it the result of serialization is what matters and he can't change the property name for some reason.